# In python, how to get subparsers to read in parent parser's argument?

Tags: python, argparse

Here is an example code:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-main_arg')
subparser=parser.add_subparser()
a=subparser.add_parser('run')
a.add_argument('required_sub_arg')
a.add_argument('arg_a')
b=subparser.add_parser('b')
parser.parse_args()
```

I want it to read in `-main_arg` if I enter `program run required_sub_arg -main_arg -arg_a`

Right now, it doesn't recognize `-main_arg` as a valid argument.

Comment: Is main-arg meant to be an argument to the main parser or the subparser?

Comment: main-arg is an argument that can be used in any subparser

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## PSA to recent readers

As this question still has visits in 2018, before doing anything this complex with argparse, please consider using [docopt](http://docopt.org/) or [click](https://palletsprojects.com/p/click/) instead. It will improve both your sanity and that of anyone who might read or modify your code. Thank you.

## Original answer

As is, you have a few issues.

First, `parser.parse_args` is a method that returns a namespace of `parser`'s arguments, so you should do something like

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then `args.main_args` to get`-main_arg` from a call like

```
program -main_arg run required_sub_arg -arg_a
```

---

Your issue with `main_arg` is that you have created a argument to `parser` named `main_arg`, and you make a call like

```
program run required_sub_arg -main_arg -arg_a
```

that refers to an argument to `a` named `main_arg`. Since `a` doesn't have such an argument, it is invalid.

In order to refer to a parser's argument from one of its subparser, you have to make said subparser inherit the arguments of its parent. This is done with

```
a=parser.add_subparser('run', parents=[parser])
```

You have mistaken subparser for child parser. See http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/argparse.html and https://code.google.com/p/argparse/issues/detail?id=54 for more informations.

Comment: Running code I put above returns an error, saying that -main_arg is not a valid argument. 

Do I need 'parents=[parser]' then?

I can do things like, program -main_arg run required_sub_arg -arg_a but cannot, program run required_sub_arg -main_arg -arg_a

Comment: So, what add_subparser do is basically create a new ArgumentParser. And when parse_arg is called, it parses the arguments of both the subparser and the original parser?

What if 2 subcommands are called simultaneously?

Comment: as far as I know, you can't call sibling subcommands simultaneously, but give it a try, one never try enough :) For more details, I suggest http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else using argparse that arrives here looking for a way to display "common" sub-parser arguments in the "main" help screen, here's one approach:

```
import argparse
common = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
common.add_argument('--shared', action='store_true', help='some shared arg')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--parent', action='store_true', help='parent only arg')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
run = subparsers.add_parser('run', parents=[common])
run.add_argument('--fast', action='store_true', help='run only arg')
parser.epilog = "--- Arguments common to all sub-parsers ---" \
    + common.format_help().replace(common.format_usage(), '')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Main help:

```
$ program.py -h
usage: program.py [-h] {run} ...

positional arguments:
  {run}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --parent    parent only arg

--- Arguments common to all sub-parsers ---
optional arguments:
  --shared  some shared arg
```

`run` sub-parser help:

```
$ program.py run -h
usage: program.py run [-h] [--shared]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --shared    some shared arg
  --fast      run only arg
```

---

To address the actual question, since the accepted answer doesn't run for me, here's some additional information on why it doesn't seem possible to truly share argparse arguments with the same name across both parent and child/sub-parser parsers.

First, the problem with the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-main_arg')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
run = subparsers.add_parser('run', parents=[parser])
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Is that it leads to the following error, because both parent `parser` and sub-parser `run` define the -h/--help argument (by default).

```
Argparse.ArgumentError: argument -h/--help: conflicting option strings: -h, --help
```

While this error can be avoided by suppressing the -h/--help option (with `add_help=False`) on either the parent or the child, it's nice to have the help option at both levels.

Another potential way to avoid conflicting help options is to move *common* arguments to a shared parser, `common`:

```
import argparse
common = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
common.add_argument('-main_arg', action='store_true')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[common])
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
run = subparsers.add_parser('run', parents=[common])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

While this appears to work on the surface, in practice, it doesn't work as intended:

```
$ program.py run  # OK
Namespace(main_arg=False)
$ program.py run -main_arg  # OK
Namespace(main_arg=True)
$ program.py -main_arg run  # BAD: expected main_arg to be True
Namespace(main_arg=False)
```

The behavior observed when parsing `program.py -main_arg run` illustrates a key relationship: a **parent argparser** and its **sub-parsers** are *independent* parsers, where the **parent** parses all arguments up to the sub-parser "command" positional argument, and then the selected **sub-parser** parses the remaining arguments in the same Namespace as the parent with no regard for attributes that may have been set by the parent.